# What does the method release from the class NSfileManager do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, nsfilemanager

The method release from the object fileManager is executed below. That's all I know at the moment. I tried searching for the meaning of the method release, but I couldn't find it.

I searched on StackOverflow:

- body:"[filemanager release];"
- filemanager release
- NSfilemanager release

I searched on Google:

- fileManager release method
- NSfilemanager release method

I also tried finding the method on developer.apple.com. I saw alot of info about the [NSfileManager class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/), but I didn't see the release method of it. I am new to Objective-C.

```
[fileManager release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is inherited from `NSObject`. it reduces reference count on an object by one. You can make use of it only when `Automatic Reference Counting` is disabled. But it should always be enabled. So enable ARC and forget about `release`

And read this : [Cocoa Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

And this: [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You may see an error like this, I believe if you're using Xcode v.5.0 or above.

[image]

Comment: Like he said - switch to ARC, *don't* call `release`